# Not able to start Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, server-error

I am working on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Lucid Lynx, have installed Ruby on Rails 3 on it. I am not able to start Rails server. I am getting the following error.

```
mah@mah-laptop:~/Desktop/projects/ver$ rails s
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:29:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `root' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I am using Rails 3.0.8 and rake version 0.8.7

I tried `bundle exec` but got same error.

Thanks for any help in advance

**UPDATE**

Here is what I get after `bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace`

```
mah@mah-laptop:~/Desktop/projects/ver$ bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Ver
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing_from_s3_library'
/home/mah/Desktop/projects/ver/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/mah/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: have you tried `bundle install`?

Comment: already tried... it didn't help.

Comment: downgrade to rails 3.0.7. then this might be fixed...!

Comment: Looks like aws-s3 gem is throwing an error. The [aws-s3](http://rubygems.org/gems/aws-s3) gem hasn't been updated since 2009, so my guess is that it's probably not compatable with rails 3.x. Maybe try using a different aws gem e.g. [aws](https://github.com/appoxy/aws/)

Comment: I'm not using it (yet), but the aws-s3 gem is in my Gemfile and I have no problems on 3.0.7 and 3.0.9.

Comment: the issue was in application.rb, it was missing (Bundler) on 7th line after the if condition. You can compare my and Ryan Bigg's application.rb files provided below. Thanks for the response... That one missing word `(Bundler)` took more than a day to debug... pheww.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that `Rails.application` isn't initialized. I didn't actually know that, [I 
cheated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.8/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb#L29).

So that then begs the question: how did you set up this application?

Perhaps this application doesn't contain a `config/application.rb` file that defines a class that inherits from `Rails::Application` and therefore is causing this problem. In my application here, I've got [this one](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee/blob/master/config/application.rb) you could use as an example.

Comment: hi Ryan. I have config/application.rb setup correctly. https://gist.github.com/1048402

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have updated my question with the errors that I get on `rake db:migrate`. Can you pls help? Thanks